# Adapter pdf list view

Tags: android, arrays, list, pdf, adapter

i'm trying to create a list view with an image and the list of the pdf with their name on a folder ( getexternalstorage/Documents )

So here is my java code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Retrieve the path and stock on namePdfList

    View deliveryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_delivery_slip,
            container, false);
    listView = (ListView) deliveryView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    File images = new File(
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Documents/");

    namePdfList = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
        }
    });

    // Fill the table pdflist with the name of the PDF

    pdflist = new Pdf[namePdfList.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < namePdfList.length; i++)
    {
        pdflist[i].setName(namePdfList[i].getName());
    }

    PdfAdapter adapter = new PdfAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.line_pdf,
            pdflist);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return deliveryView;
}
```

I retrieve all the path on "NamePdfList" , an i getname.
The list is correctly fill , but i've got an issue with the set name

```
pdflist[i].setName(namePdfList[i].getName());
```

I tried this , but same issue

```
pdflist[i].name = imagelist[i].getName();
```

So I think i'm making a big mistake with the manipulation of the object.
I just want to instantiate a table of Pdf , and fill it with the name

Here my PDF class i delete to simplify

```
  public class Pdf
{
    public String name;

    public Pdf()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Pdf(String i)
    {
        this.name = i;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Thanks to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pdflist[i] = new Pdf(namePdfList[i].getName());
```